# Error while updating the postgres database through python

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin-4

- I am trying to update a record from python. The database used is postgres.
- Name of the database is "users"
- The server is hosted on pgadmin4.
- I am taking the values from the html file and the updating the status field.
- `application.py`

```
@app.route("/enable", methods=['POST'])
def enable():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                          password="postgres",
                                          host="localhost",
                                          port="5432",
                                          database="admins")

            cursor = connection.cursor()

            user_name = request.form['user_name']
            status = 'Enable'
            print(user_name)
            print(status)
            sql_update_query = """UPDATE users SET status = %s WHERE username = '%s'"""
            record_to_update = (sql_update_query, (user_name, status))
            cursor.execute(sql_update_query, record_to_update)
            connection.commit()
            print("Record updated sucessfully")

        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            print("Error in update operation", error)

        finally:
        # closing database connection.
            if (connection):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
    return redirect(url_for('list'))
```

- The screenshot of the terminal
  [image]
- In the screenshot `admin1` is the username and `Enable` is the value I am passing as the value for the status column to be updated. By default it is `Active`.

Comment: You're writing `cursor.execute(sql_update_query, record_to_update)`, but `record_to_update` isn't actually the record, it's a tuple of the query and the record.

Change your definition of `record_to_update` to `record_to_update = (user_name, status)`, and your code may work, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: You have a little mistake in `record_to_update = (sql_update_query, (user_name, status))` should be `record_to_update = (user_name, status)`

Comment: It worked !! Thanks !! It is solved now.